# Save logs to file system from background task

Tags: java, android, file, logging, background-process

I want to add a logging system to an android app that writes debugging/event logs into a text file. The users have to be able to turn it on and off.

My app uses some 'background techniques' like AlarmManagers and Homescreen Widgets which complicates things.

I guess i have to write the variable which turns logging on/off to file and check it each time when an event calls the log method.

This seems very wasteful, especially if logging is turned off.
Making the variable static keeps it from being garbage collected for a while (but not very long) and is kind of wasteful too. I'm worried about leaking context too or having the read/write/sharedpreferences crash if it's not in a background task.

How can i go about this in a different way?

Some pseudo code:

```
logToFile("some error", Context context)

logtoFile (String error, Context context){
  if(context.checkSharedPreferencesIfLoggingIsEnabled){
    context.openFileOutput.write(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly use an event bus - when logging events and logging is turned off there are no subscribers to the event so it is discarded.  (in your example, one subscriber which implements your `logtoFile`).  Logically the same as what you described but implemented differently.  So from the caller point of view - it is simply posting an event to the bus.

Comment: Wouldn't the EventBus get garbage collected as well when the app closes?